# Multiple i tag in one line vs multiple line

Tags: html, css

I use text-align: justify for multiple `i` tag. It works well with multiple I tag in multiple lines, but when to combine in one line, it doesn't work.
You can try my jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/lhphuc210291/zvajLgfc/8/

html code

```
<div class="m_grid">
        <i>abc</i>
        <i>def</i>
  <div class="m_justify_fix"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="m_grid">
        <i>abc</i><i>def</i>
  <div class="m_justify_fix"></div>
</div>
```

css code

```
.m_grid {
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 0
}

.m_grid .m_justify_fix {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

First div tag works ok but with second div it doesn't work. I would like to know what is the differences from these two case. Because I render HTML by using angular component templateUrl. It's auto render HTML code without break line between `i` tag and css not work.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think when you write the two `i`s together, it is treated as a single word, leave a space between the two and you can see that they are aligned properly.

Comment: Try adding a `>`. I.e. `.m_grid > .m_grid_justify_fix {`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : there’s nothing to justify if there’s no whitespace between.